# select element overflows from page in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, select

I have a select element on the right side of a web page
in chrome the dropdown opens so it doesn't get cropped at the side of the page
in FF it does..

I want FF to act like Chrome

any ideas?

check it out here,
http://codepen.io/igalt/pen/Iklxp

10x!
Igal

Comment: I don't see the select menu cropped in FF 22 - which version are you using?

Comment: 22 as well.. are you sure?
did you click on it?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox (I'm using v20), the dropdown position its top / left at the bottom / left of your `<select>`, while Chrome set its top / right at the top / right of the select, positioning itself above the `<select>`.

Plus, Firefox use the inherited width (the one FF calculated, not the one you set) of the `<select>` to set the dropdown's width: thus, it's overflowing outside of the window.

I'm afraid you can't change the way the browser positions its native dropdown (I personally don't know a way to do that);

So, you might :

- Create your own select box, using `ul` and `li` to get full control of your dropdown,
- Remove the `width` property on your select, so FF won't overflow anymore.